# numpy sum does not return expected value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I found the problem when doing an assertion check.

`assert np.sum(array, axis=0, dtype=np.float32) == 1`

It works fine for some high precision arrays. But when I sum up an array `np.ones(12)/12.` it raised an assertion error and I checked the value is 0.99999994, which is not 1. But if I do not specify the `dtype` to `np.float32` it will raise error for other high precision arrays. So is there a way that I can do a sum or assertion check fitting both low-precision and high-precision arrays?

Comment: Floating point calculation can only have a certain accuracy.

Comment: Welcome to the world of floating point calculations.  `np.isclose` is a built-in numpy routine for checking if two things are equal within a given tolerance.

Comment: With doubles (`dtype='float64'`) I do get the result you want.

Comment: @TomdeGeus If I use `np.float64`, it does not work on the other array.

Comment: @ChrisMueller I will test it now. I think this should be the right approach. Thanks.

Comment: A friend just told me to use [`numpy.testing.assert_almost_equal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.testing.assert_almost_equal.html) and this works as well. Thank you all for answering.

Comment: to prevent underflow, it might be wise to keep numbers large and stay away from round-off errors... my test shows that it is best to sum first and then divide:

`np.sum(np.ones(12, dtype=np.float32))/12 == 1` evaluates to `True`.

Comment: @MymesHolcroft The array is fixed. I cannot divide them after sum. I was just illustrating the problem with `np.ones(12)/12`. In some arrays the division method is totally different, the elements won't be uniform anymore.